# SQL Query: Perform a join + group by + date condition

Tags: sql, join, group-by, having, teradata-sql-assistant

I have two tables with date information. I want to join both tables on the condition that the date specified in `Table_Y` lies in between the minimum and maximum date of `TABLE_X`.

I have the following query where I determine the minimum and maximum dates in `TABLE_X` and perform a join to include information of both tables. How should I go about including a statement to only include the rows where `bb.date between aa.min_startdate and aa.max_startdate`? Note that the date column of `TABLE_Y` is not specified in the current query as I do not want to include it in the final table.

```
SELECT
  aa.column_1,
  bb.column_2,
  bb.column_3,
  bb.column_4,
  MIN(aa.startdate) AS min_startdate,
  MAX(COALESCE(aa.enddate, CURRENT_DATE)) AS max_startdate

FROM TABLE_X AS aa

INNER JOIN TABLE Y AS bb
        ON bb.column_2 = aa.column_2
       AND bb.column_3 = aa.column_3

GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4
```

I was thinking of something in the order of a `WHERE` or `HAVING` function in combination with `bb.date between aa.min_startdate and aa.max_startdate` but this only results in errors due to the aggregate functions.

Comment: Use MAX(COALESCE(aa.enddate, CURRENT_DATE))  in the HAVING clause.

Comment: Adding `HAVING bb.date <= MAX(COALESCE(aa.enddate, CURRENT_DATE))` results in the error: `Selected non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group.` This is because `bb.date` does not belong to the `GROUP BY`. Adding it would kill the functionality of the `GROUP BY` for which I am currently using it.

Comment: Your query at present seems conflicted, you want to join `bb` on the basis of `min_startdate` and `max_startdate`, but their computation is dependent on values in `bb` (since the `bb` columns are in the `group by` clause). Do you really want the min/max start_date based on the values in `bb` or just based on `aa.column1`?

Comment: @Nick, in `TABLE_X` columns 2 - 4 are also present. They hold identical values as the same columns in `TABLE_Y`. If I am not mistaken it does not matter whether I call them from `aa` or `bb`. I do however need all four columns for the `GROUP BY` to determine the `min_startdate` and `max_enddate`.

Comment: OK, it wasn't clear that `bb.column_4` was also in `aa`. In that case why not use a CTE to compute the `min` and `max` dates and then join that to `aa` and `bb` on the appropriate column values to get your desired result?

Comment: Why not do: `HAVING MAX(bb.date) <= MAX(COALESCE(aa.enddate, CURRENT_DATE)) and MIN(bb.date) >= MIN(aa.startdate)`
Here we check the min / max of bb against min / max of aa - this means all dates of the bb group are in the wanted range..

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: @Nick Thanks! The CTE does the trick

Comment: @TheDude cool - glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

> I have two tables with date information. I want to join both tables on the condition that the date specified in Table_Y lies in between the minimum and maximum date of TABLE_X.

I would suggest something like this:

```
select . . . 
from table_y y join
     (select x.*, min(start_date) over () as min_start_date,
             max(start_date) over () as max_start_date
      from x
     ) x
     on y.date between x.min_start_date and x.max_start_date;
```

Your sample query seems to have other conditions that you have not described.  This answers the question that you have asked.